# Custom ansible module that wraps existing module

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to create a customized ansible module that "wraps" an existing one?

I often write this:

```
- name: foo
  become: true
  copy:
    src: foo/bar/baz
    dest: spam/ham/eggs
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
    mode: "0644"
```

So I want to eliminate the boilerplate:

```
- name: foo
  copyroot644:             # wraps `copy` module
    src: foo/bar/baz
    dest: spam/ham/eggs
```

Is there an easy way to do this, *without* getting knee-deep in Python? (I don't want to reinvent the wheel, just reuse the `copy` module.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893066/calling-an-ansible-module-from-another-ansible-module

Comment: @Zeitounator Well technically I asked if this can be done *without* python... That answer uses python. I hoped there was a way to do this without complicating things. In that case I'll just live with the boilerplate :)

Comment: You said `without getting knee-deep in Python`. I have absolutely no idea of your foreleg length.

Comment: @Zeitounator LOL

Comment: @Ionix I don't think there is any other alternative.

Comment: @Sriram If you add that as an answer I'll close

Comment: Sure, I will put it in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible modules are written in Python. I don't think there is any other alternative.